# Dual of a finite product of vector spaces is topologically isomorphic to the product of their duals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ normed vector spaces. Show that $E^*$ with the norm $\|.\|_p$ is topologically isomorphic to $E_1^* \times E_2^* \times \ldots \times E_n^*$ with the norm $\|.\|_q$ where $X^*$ is the dual of $X$, $1/p + 1/q =1$, $E = E_1 \times E_2 \times \ldots \times E_n$ and

$$\|(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\|_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

Comment: The most important detail: $E_1,..., E_n$ must be finite dimensional.

Comment: @s.harp The problem does not say nothing about the dimension of $E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n$. Is it false?

Comment: Your question and your title asked different things (and I suspect this may have caused confusion above). The question text seemed the more likely question so I've edited the title accordingly. If this doesn't reflect what you wanted to ask please change it.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks.

Comment: Actually, looking more carefully the question text still doesn't look right. What was the source of this problem?

Comment: From a list of exercises.